# Golang передать параметры для запроса

Tags: sql, postgresql, golang

Переписываю сейчас функцию insert в базу, пытаюсь сделать как правильно и безопасно.

Старая функция была такая

```
func Insert(Query string) {
    db, _ := db()
    tx, _ := db.Begin()
    _, _ = tx.Exec(Query)
    tx.Commit()
    db.Close()
}
```

Вот то, что получается сейчас:

```
func db() (*sql.DB, error) {
    var db *sql.DB
    var err error
    db, err = sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/journal")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return db, err
}

func IsertNow(Query string) {
    db, errdb := db()
    if errdb !=nil {
        log.Fatal(errdb)
    }


    rows := db.Prepare()
    rows.Exec()
    rows.Commit()
    db.Close()

}
```

Вопрос в том, как принять функции InsertNow параметры в запрос, они всегда будут разные (то есть их количество)

Пока мне видится принимать сам запрос (Query) а вторым параметром массив из значений, и в цикле перебирать и подставлять в запрос.

Может существует более правильный подход к этому?

Пример ниже помог, но вот что получается
В БД нужно вставить пустые значения:

```
r.ParseForm()
id_patient := r.FormValue("id_patient")
id_vrach_ortoped := r.FormValue("id_vrach_ortoped")
id_vrach_technic := r.FormValue("id_vrach_technic")
number_nar := r.FormValue("number_nar")
date_open_nar := r.FormValue("date_open_nar")
date_start_production := r.FormValue("date_start_production")
date_close_nar := r.FormValue("date_close_nar")
sum := r.FormValue("sum")

switch id_vrach_ortoped {
case "":
    id_vrach_ortoped = `NULL`
}
switch id_vrach_technic {
case "":
    id_vrach_technic = `NULL`
}
switch date_open_nar {
case "":
    date_open_nar = `NULL`
}
switch date_start_production {
case "":
    date_start_production = `NULL`
}
switch date_close_nar {
case "":
    date_close_nar = `NULL`
}
switch sum {
case "":
    sum = `NULL`
}

var query = "INSERT INTO j_nar (id_patient, id_vrach_ortoped, id_vrach_technic, number_nar, date_open_nar ,date_start_production, date_close_nar, sum) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8)"
models.ModelAddNar(query, id_patient, id_vrach_ortoped, id_vrach_technic, number_nar, date_open_nar, date_start_production, date_close_nar, sum)
```

Запрос не отрабатывает, если значения NULL. Работает только если все значения заполнены.

выдает ошибку

pq: invalid input syntax for integer: "NULL"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно так:

```
func IsertNow(Query string, Args ...interface{}) {
    db, errdb := db()
    if errdb !=nil {
        log.Fatal(errdb)
    }

    tx, txerr := db.Begin()
    if txerr == nil {
        res, reserr := tx.Exec(Query, Args...)
        if reserr == nil {
            tx.Commit()
        } else {
            // Обрабатываем ошибку команды reserr
            tx.Rollback()
        }
    } else {
        // Тут обрабатываем ошибку создания транзакции txerr
    }
    db.Close()

}
```

Тогда вызывать можно так:

```
IsertNow("INSERT INTO cantact (name,phone) VALUES ($1,$2)", "User", "+79876543210");
```

P.S.
Нужно помнить о разнице между tx.Exec(…) и tx.Query(…) подробдности см. [sql.DB](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Tx)

Comment: ругается

rows.Commit undefined (type *sql.Stmt has no field or method Commit)

Comment: а если без него, Insert не срабатывает

Comment: Хотите Commit() - тогда открывайте транзакцию. см https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Begin Сейчас исправлю ответ

Comment: Написал в "вопросе". Не совсем пойму что не так

Comment: Оформите вопрос про занесение NULL-able данных в виде отдельного вопроса - отвечу

Comment: оформил https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/656031/golang-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-null-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83