# Golang передать null значения в таблицу

Tags: postgresql, golang, insert, null

Есть такая функция:

```
func EditAddNar(rnd render.Render, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm()
    id_patient := r.FormValue("id_patient")
    id_vrach_ortoped := r.FormValue("id_vrach_ortoped")
    id_vrach_technic := r.FormValue("id_vrach_technic")
    number_nar := r.FormValue("number_nar")
    date_open_nar := r.FormValue("date_open_nar")
    date_start_production := r.FormValue("date_start_production")
    date_close_nar := r.FormValue("date_close_nar")
    sum := r.FormValue("sum")


    switch id_vrach_ortoped {
    case "":
        id_vrach_ortoped = "null"
    }
    switch id_vrach_technic {
    case "":
        id_vrach_technic = "null"
    }
    switch number_nar {
    case "":
        number_nar = "null"
    }
    switch date_open_nar {
    case "":
        date_open_nar = "null"
    }
    switch date_start_production {
    case "":
        date_start_production = "null"
    }
    switch date_close_nar {
    case "":
        date_close_nar = "null"
    }
    switch &sum {
    case "":
        sum = "null"
    }


    var query = "INSERT INTO j_nar (id_patient, id_vrach_ortoped, 
    id_vrach_technic, number_nar, date_open_nar ,date_start_production, da

   te_close_nar, sum) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8)"
   models.ModelAddNar(query, id_patient, id_vrach_ortoped, 
   id_vrach_technic, number_nar, date_open_nar, date_start_production, 
   date_close_nar, sum)

   }
```

models.ModelAddNar просто передает запрос и параметры в модель, а та уже выполняет команду.
pq ругается:

pq: invalid input syntax for integer: "NULL"

Но если все данные из r.FormParse() были не пустые, то запрос отрабатывает.
Подскажите как вставить в базу пустые (null) значения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня получается так:

```
func NullableFloat (s string) sql.NullFloat64 {
    if s != "" {
        value, err := strconv.ParseFloat(s, 64)
        if err == nil {
            return sql.NullFloat64{value, true}
        }
    }
    return sql.NullFloat64{}
}
func NullableInt (s string) sql.NullInt64 {
    if s != "" {
        value, err := strconv.ParseInt(s, 10, 64)
        if err == nil {
            return sql.NullInt64{value, true}
        }
    }
    return sql.NullInt64{}
}
func NullableString (s string) sql.NullString {
    return sql.NullString{s, s != ""}
}
func EditAddNar(rnd render.Render, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm()
    id_patient := r.FormValue("id_patient")
    id_vrach_ortoped := r.FormValue("id_vrach_ortoped")
    id_vrach_technic := r.FormValue("id_vrach_technic")
    number_nar := r.FormValue("number_nar")
    date_open_nar := r.FormValue("date_open_nar")
    date_start_production := r.FormValue("date_start_production")
    date_close_nar := r.FormValue("date_close_nar")
    sum := r.FormValue("sum")


    models.ModelAddNar(`INSERT INTO j_nar (
        id_patient,
        id_vrach_ortoped,
        id_vrach_technic,
        number_nar,
        date_open_nar,
        date_start_production,
        date_close_nar,
        sum
        ) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8)`,
        id_patient,
        NullableInt(id_vrach_ortoped),
        NullableInt(id_vrach_technic),
        NullableInt(number_nar),
        NullableString(date_open_nar),
        NullableString(date_start_production),
        NullableString(date_close_nar),
        NullableFloat(sum))
}
```

Более подробно про NULL-абельные занчение см. [Go: Working effectively with database nulls](https://marcesher.com/2014/10/13/go-working-effectively-with-database-nulls/)
Так-же документация по [database/sql](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/) будет полезной

P.S. Если интересно, то можно посмотреть более удобную работу с генерацией SQL выражений "на лету" https://play.golang.org/p/vR-BEwGBef

Comment: спасибо, завтра попробую.

Comment: А если нужно проверить не string а указатель на массив?

Comment: Про массивы можно посмотреть https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq Ну а если идти дальше "в глубь" то читать про https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/ и интерфейсы `Valuer` и `Scanner`см. https://husobee.github.io/golang/database/2015/06/12/scanner-valuer.html